# .htaccess issue with RewriteRule for JS files that have a specifc prefix

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to allow users to access JS files prefixed with wp- by stripping the prefix. However it does affect other files in the directory that do not have the prefix. I know I am missing something somewhere, here is the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?includes/js/(.*).js$ /wp-includes/js/wp-$1.js [QSA,L]
```

With that rule urls like `/wp-includes/js/wp-file.js` can be accessed at `includes/js/file.js` however, files like `/wp-includes/js/no-prefix.js` cannot be accessed at `includes/js/no-prefix.js`.

I know it must has to do with my rewrite rule format. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rule you need to add to your `/.htaccess` (root folder)

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-includes/js/wp-$1\.js -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^includes/js/([^/]+)\.js$ /wp-includes/js/wp-$1.js [L]
```

*Note*: put this **before** WP's main rewrite rule.

Short explanation: if url is `/includes/js/xxx.js`, it first checks that `/wp-includes/js/wp-xxx.js` physically exists. If so, it is internally rewritten.

**Warning**: Using `mod_rewrite` along with WP can lead to issues. Shouldn't be a problem in this context but sometimes it is a better idea to do it thanks to WP's built-in rewrite system.